# RabbitMq server setup on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq

Recently I tried to use Rabbitmq to try AMQP in our project. For installation I followed the steps mentioned on the offical RabbitMQ site. It created a Rabbitmq.config.example file in appdata. I renamed it to rabbitmq.config file. But even after that in logs I continuously get these messages

> =INFO REPORT==== 7-Dec-2015::19:21:14 === accepting AMQP connection <0.377.0> ([::1]:55084 -> [::1]:5672)
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 7-Dec-2015::19:21:14 === closing AMQP connection <0.377.0> ([::1]:55084 -> [::1]:5672): {bad_header,<<"GET / HT">>}

How to make my server up and running?
When I opened the config file, everything seems to be commented. Should I uncomment any part of it?

Comment: you need to provide some more information about this. Is your server not starting up? what is the exception in the console?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue on my ubuntu system.

Try this command:

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel rabbitmq_management` (with sudo privileges)

and open localhost:15672.